# accessing this class in jQuery using this keyword

Tags: jquery

How to access a class using this keyword, is this possible in jQuery.

How to access this class.

```
 $(this).("class");
```

```js
$(".b").click(function () {
  var b=$(this).parent(".c").text();
  alert(b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <span class="c">45</span>
  <input type="button" value="send" class="b">
</div>
<div class="a">
  <span class="c">63</span>
  <input type="button" value="send" class="b">
</div>
```

I want to get this of a class since I am having two element of same class name.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please post a sample of your HTML.

Comment: `$(this).attr('class')`? But you may actually want `hasClass()`.

Comment: how to access a class using this keyword

Comment: Put clarification in your question, not in comments. (And repeating yourself doesn't help.)

Comment: Would be great if you can share the DOM and what does `this` refers to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4n6ou0ka/5/ code is here

Comment: We'd have been done 44 minutes ago if you had posted the HTML as requested. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

span with class `c` is sibling of clicked button. You need to use:

```
var b=$(this).prevAll(".c").text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/84tgt3cg/)**

Answer (score 2):

To access any attribute (not only class), use `.attr()`:

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

To set attribute to some value:

```
$(this).attr('class', 'redDot');
```

**OR** if you want to access individual element of all elements by same class:

```
$.each($('.class'), function(index, element) {
   $(this).css('color', 'red'); // same as $(element).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Or directly: `$('.class').eq(0).css('color', 'red');`